# More of a logic question about equivalence

Tags: logic

If $a \Rightarrow b$ and $a \Rightarrow c$, does that mean that $b \iff c$?

Comment: No, take $a$:"$n\geqslant 3$", $b:$"$n\geqslant 2$" and $c:$"$n\geqslant 1$", then $a\Rightarrow b$ and $a\Rightarrow c$ but we don't have $b\iff c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for example $a$ could be the statement "$n$ is a multiple of $6$", $b$ could be "$n$ is a multiple of $2$", and $c$ "$n$ is a multiple of $3$", where $n$ is some integer. Then $a\Rightarrow b$ and $a\Rightarrow c$, but $b\not\Rightarrow c$ and $c\not\Rightarrow b$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The claim of $(a\to b)$ and $(a\to c)$ asserts that "Both $b$ and $c$ are true *if* $a$ is true."

However this asserts *nothing* about the values of $b$ or $c$ when $a$ is *false*.